# Investigation of hacking or attack cases by meta transaction

Tags: attacks, meta-transactions

I'm making a dapp that delegate and pays for gas fees using meta transactions. I am thinking of using ERC2771.
I'm concerned about the security of the ability to pay for gas on the blockchain.
If you know of any **hacks or attacks using meta transactions**, please share them.